# Local property Should Be Explicitly Provided

Tags: facebook

I cannot see the share in my facebook wall through a like button on my site

I used https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

I have a warning:

" Warnings That Should Be Fixed

The Property INFERRED og: local property Should Be Explicitly Provided, Even if a value INFERRED Can Be From Other tags. "

Og: local, I found info here :
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/opengraph/internationalization/

So I've added :

```
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="fr_FR" />
```

But that does not solve the problem :/

PS: i have a problem also with google +1, when i press the button he change the color to red

Answer (score 1):

About locale property: you must add primary, not alternate locale.
I've added `<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />` to my site `<head>` and it works.